# How to read part of big datafile in Python, C or Java?

Tags: java, python, c, file, binary-data

2.6 GB, binary file of 32-bit signed integers, 100 elements is each row.

I can read line by line in Java with:

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("input.rawdata"))
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    int idata = dis.readInt();
    % DO  THE NECESSARY TO LOAD idata IN A VARIABLE ARRAY % 
}
dis.close();
```

But if I wish to read only 505th line without reading the initial 504 lines, then how to do it?

Or if data is 100 x 1000 matrix and wish to read only the rectangle of 15 to 80th row & 100 to 200th column. then how to achieve this in any of the above three languages (preferably Python & Java).

Suggestions related to code efficiency are very much welcome.

Comment: I guess you want MMAP?

Comment: Read up on `fseek()` and take it from there.

Comment: What is the meaning of a row in a binary file?

Comment: Thank You @NPE & vaultah. The function seek(file_pointer_location) is exactly what I was looking for; some how I missed learning this function in CS-101 course work. 
and MMAAP looks like a smarter way of doing it, i'd surely try it sometimes.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck It was actually the data of a radar acquisition, and here line is pixels along range direction. data is sort of a image file you can say. When you take data from a commercial vendor, he gives you a file with proper inbuilt header, and with proper separators. Unlike in case of Radar acquisition, where baud-rate is critical we cannot have luxury of adding separator while logging. That's why we log as binary file (this saves some memory & processing load I guess) and later during our file handling we separate those lines from these GBs long binary strings.

Comment: If the lines have the constant length, then you can `fseek` to the right position, and suggested by NPE.

Answer (score 0):

In C, provided you know the size of the file in bytes, something like:

```
#define FILESIZE [file size in bytes]
#define NUMROWS [number of rows]
#define NUMCOLS [number of columns]
#define cnk_size(X,Y) (X*Y)
#define ENDROW [desired ending row]
#define SRTROW [desired starting row]
#define ENDCOL [desired ending col]
#define SRTCOL [desired starting col]


void* data = malloc(FILESIZE*sizeof(unsigned char));
fgets((char*)data,FILESIZE,stdin);

void* chunk = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*cnk_size(ENDROW-SRTROW,ENDCOL-SRTCOL));

register i = SRTROW;
register j = SRTCOL;

register datptr = (unsigned int)data; 
register cnkptr = (unsigned int)cnkptr; 

for(i = SRTROW; i < ENDROW; i++)
    for(j = SRTCOL; j < ENDCOL; j++)
        *((char*)cnkptr++) = *((char*)(datptr + i*NUMCOL + j));
```

in terms of speed probably could remove the for loops for optimization but your not getting much faster than this, and java / python probably wont come close. (Your gated by fgets() most likely).
To pass the file to the program:

```
bash -$$ .\your-program-name < your-file-name
```

If you do not want to load the whole file into memory, look up the split invocation:
https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/split-invocation.html
Source: My rusty pooling assignment.